Base change and tensor product of algebras
Let $K, L$ be commutative rings and let $K$ be a subring of $L$. And let us denote a free associative $K$-algebra corresponding to a set $X$ as $K\langle t_i\rangle_{i\in X}$.
Is it true that for any sets $X$, $Y$ and for any elements $\{w_j\}_{j\in Y}$ of an algebra $K\langle t_i\rangle_{i\in X}$ there exists $L$-algebra isomorphism $$L\langle t_i\rangle_{i\in X}/(w_j)_{j\in Y}\simeq \frac{ L\otimes_K K \langle t_i\rangle_{i\in X}}{(w_j)_{j\in Y}}=:A?$$
My attempt is to consider an algebra homomorphism $f\colon L\langle t_i\rangle_{i\in X}\to A$, defined as $f(t_i):=[1\otimes t_i]_{(w_j)}$. It's easy to check that $f$ is surjective and that $\operatorname{Ker} f \supset (w_j)$. But how can I establish that $\operatorname{Ker} f \subset (w_j)$?
Thanks for paying attention

An isomorphism is an invertible homomorphism. Use that, and the universal properties of course. Forget about injective + bijective.

But I am pretty sure that this is a duplicate. I suggest to use site search.

@MartinBrandenburg what key words may I use?

Tensor product quotient algebra isomorphism, such things
